# Is it possible to use an external camera with an iPhone or iPad for Zoom/Facetime

Tags: iphone, ipad, facetime, webcam

I am trying to figure out if it is at all possible connect an external webcam to an iPhone or iPad, as I am trying to build something that improve quality and changes camera positioning during video calls, either on Facetime or Zoom.

Is there any way to do this with a USB webcam, or any way to do this with a wireless webcam? Would the only way to do this be essentially build a specialized app to do this?